# Play 2 Ebean with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, playframework, ebean

When I try to use MongoDB driver in my play framework application's application.conf as

```
db.default.driver=com.mongodb
```

I am getting `Driver not found` error. I have configured dependency in Build.scala for MongoDB driver.

I am using official Java driver for MongoDB `mongo-java-driver` v 2.11.1. I want this driver to be used with Ebean.

What is the correct class name to be used in the `db.default.driver` to get this working?

Comment: I don't think that Ebean supports MongoDB. As far as I know, it only supports relational databases through JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EBean doesn't support MongoDB, it only works with relational databases as it is a JPA-compliant driver.

[Here](https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Java-MongoDb-Jackson-exemple) you have an example using Java and MongoDB which may help you to bootstrap your project

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and quick response.

Comment: @PereVillega where is the example? You said "here you have an example.."

Comment: @poornerd the word here contains a link to the example.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo"ReactiveMongo Support to Play! Framework 2.3")!

This is a plugin for Play 2.3, enabling support for ReactiveMongo  - reactive, asynchronous and non-blocking Scala driver for MongoDB.

ReactiveMongo is a scala driver that provides fully non-blocking and asynchronous I/O operations.

ReactiveMongo-link  [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/)